# Use LEFT OUTER Join to find a field summtion of multiple tables MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables, let's assume three table + User table.

All tables have a foreign key called email and a score field.

**user:**

```
id    email
1     a@mail.com
2     b@email.com
```

**t1:**

```
id  email   score
1   a@mail.com  2
2   a@mail.com  7
3   a@mail.com  8
4   b@mail.com  3
```

**t2:**

```
id  email   score
1   a@mail.com  4
```

**t3:**

```
id  email   score
1   b@mail.com  5
```

I want to find the sum of every user Score from the three tables,
example:

```
email           S1   S2   S3    Summation
a@mail.com      4   17    0         21
```

**This is my sql:**

```
    SELECT u.email as uEmail ,sum (a.score) as S1,sum(w.score) as S2,sum(boo.score) as S3, 
sum(a.score + w.score + boo.score) as Summition 
 FROM user u 
 LEFT OUTER Join t1 a On u.email= a.email  
 LEFT OUTER Join t2 w On u.email=w.email  
 LEFT OUTER Join t3 boo On u.email=boo.email group by uEmail ;
```

I get wrong values with S2 as it should be only 4:

```
uEmail      S1  S2  S3  Summition
a@mail.com  17  12      
b@mail.com  3       5
```

I found  the reason when i remove group by:

```
SELECT u.email as uEmail ,(a.score) as S1,(w.score) as S2,(boo.score) as S3, 
(a.score + w.score + boo.score) as Summition 
 FROM user u 
 LEFT OUTER Join t1 a On u.email= a.email  
  LEFT OUTER Join t2 w On u.email=w.email  
   LEFT OUTER Join t3 boo On u.email=boo.email  ;
```

The value of Score's value **4**  repeated everytime:

```
uEmail      S1  S2  S3  Summition
a@mail.com  2   4       
a@mail.com  7   4       
a@mail.com  8   4   
b@mail.com  3       5
```

Comment: First off, using email as a foreign key is a really bad idea. You should use the id column in the user table. Your query should be just on the user's table, with sub-selects collecting the scores from each table.

Comment: Yes, I should use id instead, I will try to make sub-select. thanks

Comment: Thanks, It's work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one also has the Summation of s1 + s2 +s3

```
select u.email, sum(s1) as S1, sum(s2) as S2, sum(s3) as S3, sum(s1+s2+s3) as Summation
from (select email, score as s1, 0 as s2, 0 as s3 from t1
      union
      select email, 0 as s1, score as s2, 0 as s3 from t2
      union 
      select email, 0 as s1, 0 as s2, score as s3 from t3) s
left join user u
on u.email = s.email
group by u.email
order by u.email
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! khorshid

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    u.`email`,
    (SELECT SUM(`score`) FROM `t1` a WHERE a.`email` = u.`email`) as s1,
    (SELECT SUM(`score`) FROM `t2` b WHERE b.`email` = u.`email`) as s2,
    (SELECT SUM(`score`) FROM `t3` c WHERE c.`email` = u.`email`) as s3
FROM `users` u
```

I would strongly suggest not using email as a foreign key. Use the users.id column instead. Emails can change, and you do not want the headache of having to update all of the related rows in multiple tables if the user's email changes.